# I want to select as much as member CustomUser(which is Agents Model instances) while creating a project

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Filter A foreignkey child model instance in a form field based on the parent value selected in another field in the same field

```
class Agents(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numero_telephone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    departement_id = models.ForeignKey(Departements, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    role_id = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    profile_pic = models.FileField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

class Projets(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    projet_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    departement_id = models.ForeignKey(Departements, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1) #need to give defauult course
    manager_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True,blank=True)
    membres_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: Hi. Don't put code into an image and paste only link. Put your code directly into the question post. Otherwise noone can actually help you.

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation

Comment: Ok, now you can explain your problem and share related code. The Question you have posted is not clear.